# Responsive Font Size Java

Tags: java, fonts, responsive

I'm making a 2D game in Java and I'm trying to make it responsive (only in 16:9 aspect ratio). But to do that, I need my font size to change as well, depending on the screen size. How do I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: This question is way too broad! Put some effort in your research and try to solve the problem yourself. When you have a specific programming related question, come back and ask that!

Comment: Without any specification on what library/framework you are using it's impossible to provide any meaningful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of specifications missing for the question, but the basic concept might be the following:

- Listen the events for the container resizing [with a ComponentListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ComponentListener.html#componentResized(java.awt.event.ComponentEvent))
- In the Event listener make the resize logic, for example by increasing the font size until the text does not fit in the container.

See [this example](http://java-sl.com/tip_adapt_label_font_size.html).